# Changes Takes Long To Reflect With Firebase Hosting On Custom Domain

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vite, firebase-hosting

I have a Vue Js app with the latest version of Vite and Vue Router.

When I push changes to `Firebase Hosting`, the changes reflect instantly on the Firebase provided domain (e.g mycompany.web.app), but takes days to be reflected on my custom domain (e.g mycompany.com)

When I open the custom domain (e.g mycompany.com), you see a blank page with error on browser console.

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

From firefox this is displayed

> Loading module from “https://staging.company.app/assets/index.3794b176.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

> Loading failed for the module with source “https://staging.company.app/assets/index.3794b176.js”.

The Firebase provided domain loads the page with the newly deployed changes without any issues.
In `firebase.json`

```
{
  "target": "qa",
  "public": "dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried adding a cache policy on the firebase.json without any luck.
I also deployed the app on Netlify and it seems to work well.

### *** Updated

When `index.html` changed title and application is redeployed, the browser does not change the title, still refers to previous title

Comment: "Expected JavaScript but got text/html" probably means something's 404ing.'

Comment: @ceejayoz But page loads fine with firebase provided domain, on custom domain displays that error and page fail to load. May it be is a problem with cache?

Comment: Are both hosted exactly the same way?

Comment: The app is deployed using this command `firebase deploy --only hosting:staging -P qa`,   then through the console added custom domain to the site

Comment: @ceejayoz om firefox console displays `Loading module from “https://staging.company.app/assets/index.3794b176.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Comment: And what happens if you open `https://staging.company.app/assets/index.3794b176.js` in your browser?

Comment: @ceejayoz when i open `https://staging.company.app/assets/index.3794b176.js` it loads fine with no error on console. I don't get it, whats really wrong here?

Comment: When you look at the network request in your browser, what is the `Content-Type` header sent?

Comment: @ceejayoz Response Headers indicate `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, but the file is `index.3794b176.js`, a JS file

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recently where the Firebase provided domain worked fine but my custom domain would croak with a similar error. I solved it finally by doing

> firebase deploy

instead of

> firebase deploy --only hosting

Hope this helps!